# How to edit templates created in the block editor in code / template files not updating

Tags: php, templates, block-editor

I'm a beginner when it comes to PHP so have been building my page templates in the Block editor editor [appearance > editor].

But I've reached a point where I need to work in PHP/code (to make a recent post list which pulls all of each post's images to make a slider, rather than a featured image).

However, I haven't been able to locate the working template files made in the block editor. The .html files in my theme > templates folder aren't updating and making changes to them has no effect on the site.

Why is this?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You are obviously using full site editing theme if you have HTML templates. For classic themes you have PHP templates and there you can enter php code.

Full site editing html templates use only blocks in their templates and you can't use PHP there. You can only use existing or build new block and place block template code there.

So either switch to classic theme, or use existing blocks in your theme to build a template or learn to develop blocks if existing block don't fit your needs, which is more demanding than PHP development in classic theme templates.